# is javascript new Date() created at same time on 2 diff machines/timezones exactly same?

Tags: javascript, date

I wanted to know if a date object created at any point of time differ based on time zones or not. I tried this by executing new Date().getTime() once for IST and immediately again by setting my PC time zone to GMT. The resultant values are:

- IST - 1633334780053
- GMT - 1633334788831

A difference of around 8000 milliseconds

From this it seems that datetime objects created at same moment are exactly same no matter in which time zone they are created. Please suggest if this understanding is correct or is there more to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is detailed in the JavaScript specification: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-objects.

More information is in the MDN docs [Date.getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime):

> The getTime() method returns the number of milliseconds* since the Unix Epoch.

> *JavaScript uses milliseconds as the unit of measurement, whereas Unix Time is in seconds.

> getTime() always uses UTC for time representation. For example, a client browser in one timezone, getTime() will be the same as a client browser in any other timezone.

So `new Date().getTime()` will always return the number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, *regardless* of the client / machine timezone setting.

Comment: This might be slightly misleading but not intentionally. The biggest problem here is making sure that both machines are creating a `Date` object referring to the same point in time. With `new Date()` (no parameters) which runs at the same time on two machines, that's always the case. If parameters are passed into the constructor. For example,  `new Date("2021-10-04T10:00:00Z")` - it will create a date object in UTC. However, `new Date("2021-10-04T10:00:00")` (no `Z`) will base on local time zone, so `getTime()` will return different values on different machines.

Comment: Thanks @VLAZ, the discussion was about generating current date time by passing no parameters - new Date();
If we pass same datetime as string parameter without specifying a time zone, that would be 2 different moments in time, hence value  obtained from getTime() on these objects would be different.

Answer (score 4):

You're right. Two different date time objects created at the same point of time are same no matter the time zone.

They can be formatted to their corresponding timezone representation using javascript.

One important thing to be noted is that the date time object created uses the system's date time configuration to find the correct time. If the system's date and time configurations are correct and in sync, then the date time object created in the browser will be correct and will match the system time at the time of creating that object.